# Elements are invisible in GridLayout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

Any elements I put in the GridLayout, they become invisible in the preview window inside activity_main. When I run the app, the element appears where it should in the emulator, but not in the activity_main preview mode.
I'm guessing it's an attribute setting for GridLayout, but I'm not sure where to look.

[image]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/btnText"
            app:layout_column="30"
            app:layout_row="0" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also I noticed this error from the StackTrace

[image]

Here's the build.gradle requested. I wasn't sure which one you wanted so here's both.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.annovak.gridlayout"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
}
```

Comment: try clean build the project

Comment: I tried clean and then rebuild, but issue still persists.

Comment: I found a solution by changing  <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout to <GridLayout>. Is there an issue with using just <GridLayout> since it works.

Comment: Issue will be depend on OS(if it is custom OS then may be ) with using GridLayout directly .but don't is very rare to got issue with GridLayout .

Comment: Please put your build.gradle file

Comment: I added the build.gradle file above

Answer (score 0):

In your app - build.gradle make sure you import:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1
```